# Enviar Dados De Um Formulario Diretamente Para API

Tags: php, javascript, html

Ola !! Tenho um cadastro em php simples com alguns dados de clientes, preciso enviar esses dados  para uma API com POST de um erp da nossa empresa e gravar esses dados no banco tambem, sou iniciante e estou apanhando muito

Comment: Você quer enviar os dados de um formulário para uma API externa e salvar no seu próprio banco?

Comment: Sim, tenho ate o link do site aqui https://erp.bluesoft.com.br/api/#/core/incluirUsingPOST_1

Comment: Estou usando PHP

Comment: meus dados ja estão sendo salvos no banco !

Comment: Vou sugerir que pesquise sobre ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionarei um exemplo básico de como provavelmente você fará com que seus dados sejam enviados para uma API e salvos na sua base de dados:

```js
//ESTE SCRIPT FOI FEITO UTILIZANDO A BIBLIOTECA JQUERY
 //LEMBRE-SE DE ADICIONA-LA NO HEAD DA PÁGINA

 //EVENTO DE CLICAR NO SUBMIT
 $("#send").click(function(event){
  
  //EVITAR QUE O FORMULÁRIO SEJA SUBMETIDO ANTES DO ENVIO PARA A API
  event.preventDefault();

  //ENVIA PARA A API
  $.ajax({
   //METODO DE ENVIO
   type: "POST",
   //URL PARA QUAL OS DADOS SERÃO ENVIADOS
   url: "erp.bluesoft.com.br/beta/api",
   //DADOS QUE SERÃO ENVIADOS
   data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
   //TIPOS DE DADOS QUE O AJAX TRATA
   dataType: "json",
   //CASO DÊ TUDO CERTO NO ENVIO PARA A API
   success: function(){
    //SUBMETE O FORMULÁRIO PARA A ACTION DEFINIDA NO CABEÇALHO
    $("#formulario").submit();
   }
  });
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <form id="formulario" method="POST" action="insert.php">
    <label>nome</label>
  <input type="text" name="nome"></br>
   <label>sobrenome</label>
    <input type="text" name="sobrenome"></br>
  <label>bairro</label>
    <input type="text" name="bairro"></br>
  <label>CEP</label>
    <input type="text" name="cep"></br>
  <input type="submit" id="send" value="Enviar">
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tenho enviar os dados via Curl, ta osso mans kk